# Is this correct factory method pattern?

Tags: php, factory-pattern

I know that there are many similar questions, but I don't understand most of those questions because I'm not sure if I know what a factory method pattern is..

so..after reading many examples over the web, I came up with the following simple classes.

Am I doing it correctly?

```
abstract class Driveable
{
    abstract public function start();
    abstract public function stop();

}

class CoupeDriveable extends Driveable
{
    public function start()
    {
    }

    public function stop()
    {
    }
}

class MotorcycleDriveable extends Driveable
{
    public function start()
    {
    }

    public function stop()
    {
    }   
}

class SedanDriveable extends Driveable
{
    public function start()
    {
    }

    public function stop()
    {
    }   
}

class DriveableFactory
{
    static public function create($numberOfPeople){

        if( $numberOfPeople == 1 )
        {
            return new MotorcycleDriveable;
        }       
        elseif( $numberOfPeople == 2 )
        {
            return new CoupleDriveable;
        }
        elseif( $numberOfPeople >= 3 && $numberOfPeople < 4)
        {
            return SedanDriveable;
        }
    }
}


class App
{
    static public function getDriveableMachine($numberOfPeople)
    {
        return DriveableFactory::create($numberOfPeople);
    }
}


$DriveableMachine = App::getDriveableMachine(2);
$DriveableMachine->start();
```

Comment: should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @silent // ah...thanks!! didn't know stackexchange has codereview website.

Comment: no problem, just helping to promote the other stackexchange

Comment: I think it's neat that you implemented it by passing the number of people as a parameter, but for flexibility, an option would be to have a create method for each type of vehicle.
<br/>

I know this isn't about the concepts of factory pattern, but your logic for sedan creation will only return a SedanDriveable if the $numberOfPeople is exactly equal to 3. I think a sedan should hold at least 4 or 5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's a correct implementation of the `factory method` pattern.

**Edit** +1 for silent's comment. Should indeed be on coderewiew, didn't thought about that.

Comment: mAu // ahhhh great...finally I got it!

Answer (score 3):

To be exact: This is a **Factory pattern**, not a **Factory method pattern**.

The difference is that in the Factory pattern you have a separate factory object (`DriveableFactory`), whereas in the Factory method pattern, the `create()` method would be a member of the `Driveable` base class. I'm not familiar with php, and the pattern doesn't seem to be applicable to your concrete scenario anyway, so I cannot give you a code example here.

But in any case, you have to distinguish the two patterns. I know that there is a lot of confusion around them, and the Wikipedia entry for *Factory method pattern* is just plain wrong - among a lot of other sources that can be found on the web. But it's better to be exact on this, because it's essential for communication to mean the same things when you're using the same words...

HTH - Thomas

Comment: Thomas Weller // Could you please elaborate more? If Wikipedia entry is incorrect, I don't think I can find a better answer some where else..