# How to convert this simple factory to factory method?

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory

I've asked a question "Is this correct factory method pattern?" [Is this correct factory method pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976974/is-this-correct-factory-method-pattern)

and..then...asked the same question on codereview.stackexchange.com accoriding to a commenter's advice. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/is-this-correct-factory-method-pattern

So...three people said..my code is a factory method, but a user pointed out that my code is actually a simple factory.

As I keep reading other examples over the web, I start thinking that my code is actually a simple factory.

My code:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/is-this-correct-factory-method-pattern

How do I convert my code into a factory method pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually using a simple factory in your example and it looks fine to me. With these requirements, there is no need to go for factory method pattern.

However I'll try to explain factory method in this context. By definition:

Factory method pattern defines an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate.  Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to
subclasses.

So basically you'll have an abstract factory class which defines which creational methods will be available in concrete factories and the latter will decide which concrete objects to create.

There is one example I can think of in your scenerio. lets say you have Drivables of different makes (say BMW and Honda). So you'll have classes like `BMWCoupeDrivable,
BMWMotorcycleDrivable, BMWSedanDrivable, HondaCoupeDrivable, HondaMotorcycleDrivable, HondaSedanDrivable`. You might also add more makes in future. In this case, you are probably
better off using factory method.

```
    abstract class DriveableFactory
    {
        abstract public function create($numberOfPeople);

        //-- Other methods here which manipulate the drivable
        //-- e.g. testDrive()
    }

    class BMWDriveableFactory extends DriveableFactory
    {
        public function create($numberOfPeople){

            if( $numberOfPeople == 1 )
            {
                return new BMWMotorcycleDriveable;
            }       
            elseif( $numberOfPeople == 2 )
            {
                return new BMWCoupleDriveable;
            }
            elseif( $numberOfPeople >= 3 && $numberOfPeople < 4)
            {
                return BMWSedanDriveable;
            }
        }
    }

    class HondaDriveableFactory extends DriveableFactory
    {
        public function create($numberOfPeople){

            if( $numberOfPeople == 1 )
            {
                return new HondaMotorcycleDriveable;
            }       
            elseif( $numberOfPeople == 2 )
            {
                return new HondaCoupleDriveable;
            }
            elseif( $numberOfPeople >= 3 && $numberOfPeople < 4)
            {
                return HondaSedanDriveable;
            }
        }
    }
```

For better explanation, I'd suggest reading Head First Design Pattern.